# create folders based on a file name and move those files into that folder

Tags: file, filenames, directory

I am a novice in creating automated tasks.  I need to create folders based on a file name and move those files into that folder.  There are instructions, but I am a little scared to try...little help?

Comment: Which programming language do you use? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Split this into two steps (assume using `C++` in `Windows` OS):

1. Create a folder.

   ```
   #include <Windows.h>
   void create_folder(char* Path)
   {
       char DirName[256];
       char* p = Path;
       char* q = DirName;  

       while(*p)
       {
           if (('\\' == *p) || ('/' == *p))
           {
               if (':' != *(p-1))
               {
                   CreateDirectory(DirName, NULL);
               }
           }
           *q++ = *p++;
           *q = '\0';
       }
       CreateDirectory(DirName, NULL);
   }
   ```
2. Write the file to the folder you just created (as you normally do).